# How to control&edit shared task tags in eclipse using subclibse svn?

Tags: eclipse, svn, tags, task, subclipse

We are using subclipse plugin to work on an SVN repository with eclipse Luna.
Me and my work partner are using custom task tags (project>properties>task tags : TODO, FIXME... and we add custom ones). At the beginning we added new task tags, each one of us on his own pc.
but now it suddenly started syncing it!! I searched the web for some info about this and couldn't find any...
by syncing it I mean that tags I added on my pc suddenly started being identified on my partner's pc. all the tags on my partner's project disappeared from the project>properties>task tags. when I add (or erase) new task tag, it wont effect the project and it will not be identified on the project.

for example:
I add new task tag with the name TEST. I press OK and eclipse asks me if I want to make the changes affective now. I click yes and it seems to be rebuilding. and still - the task tag is not identified!

help!
any one got any idea how to control this?? Im guessing I can somehow edit the shared task tags but I have no idea how.

thanks,
its really important for us:-)